# Line divs up using % width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a page where there is a line of 4 cards, each with width: 25%. Below that I have a line with 3 cards that I want to line up with the first 3 cards of the line above. The cards also have a margin which means that when it divides the card's width with 25% the 3 cards are bigger. Any idea how to fix this?

```css
.section-wrapper {display: flex}
.sessions-card, .earnings-card {flex:0 0 25%; margin: 0 10px; border: 2px solid black; height: 200px}

.session-wrapper:first-child {margin-left: -10px}
.session-wrapper:last-child {margin-right: -10px}
```

```html
<h1>Sessions</h1>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="sessions-card approved"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card completed"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card pending"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card cancelled"></div>
</div>

<h1>Earnings</h1>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex: 0 0 25%; instead of the width: 25%

Comment: excellent, thanks! Please submit that as an answer!

Comment: I realised I missed out of some css. any chance I can still use flex: 0 0 25% with just some tweaks? Ive updated the CSS. Since when I use  0 0 25% it is expanding the boxes outside of the 100% width

Comment: If I use flex-shrink the cards are uneven again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `width`, you can do it with the `flex` *property* and if `20px` is the desired `margin` between them, you'd need to use some `calc()`, esp. if you want for the *first* and *last* one to be touching the *parents* edges:

```css
.section-wrapper {display: flex; background: lightblue}

/* can also do it with the "justify-content: space-between;" and "margin-right: auto" set on the last ".earnings-card" */

.sessions-card, .earnings-card {
  /*width: 25%;*/
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 15px); /* -15px because of the -20px left & right margin devided by 4 = 5px; 20px - 5px = 15px */
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sessions-card:first-child,
.earnings-card:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sessions-card:last-child,
.earnings-card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sessions</h1>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="sessions-card approved"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card completed"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card pending"></div>
  <div class="sessions-card cancelled"></div>
</div>

<h1>Earnings</h1>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
  <div class="earnings-card"></div>
</div>
```